# C++ Variable Confusion

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming C++. Consider the following code:

```
int a;
a = 4;
int b = a;
b++;
```

At the end of this code, `a=4` and `b=5`. I would like it if `a=5` through modifying `b`. How do I modify my code so that this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want `b` to be an alias for `a` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the code to do what you want, `b` would need to be a *reference* to `a`.

`int a; a = 4; int &b = a; b++;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
a = 4;
int *b = &a;
(*b)++;
```